# Where does the unauthenticated redirect happen in Devise authenticate_user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect, devise

I am trying to add a URL parameter to my `/sign_in` route using the Devise gem in Rails 4. I have `before_filter :authenticate_user!` in my `application_controller.rb`.

I am wondering where exactly the redirect happens if the user is unauthenticated. I need to add a parameter at this point so I can make some customizations to the resulting view. I have tried overriding the `authenticate_user!` method and adding my own `redirect_to` if the user is not signed in but then I get a too many redirects error since, as I said, this method is in a before_filter and is firing more than once.

Does anyone know where I can access this redirect URL?

Comment: Have you tried the directions shown in the devise wiki entry: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-when-the-user-can-not-be-authenticated

Comment: I am trying to achieve something slightly different than this. Essentially I am trying to append a parameter to the `/sign_in` URL. So I need to know where I can alter this. Right now, if the user is unauthenticated it just "automagically" goes to the sign in page.